# Swift 2 - Appending string to string (concatenation)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to extract values out of an array and concatenate all the values in one string like the following

```
var ingredient: String

for tag in tags {
   if let text = tag.titleLabel?.text {
      ingredient += " \(text)"
   }
}

recipe.ingredients = ingredient
```

But I Xcode complains:

`Variable "ingredient" passed by reference before being initialized`

I think it complains that ingredient is initialized but has no value to start with for concatenation. Is that right?
How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recipe.ingredients = tags.flatMap { $0.titleLabel?.text }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

Not exactly the same, but this way it's safe and in one line.

Comment: This turns out to be exactly what I wanted. I think my approach was failing and will fail 99% because it won't have value until user put some value, is that right? I'm just trying to learn :)

Comment: To be exact, it will fail 100% :). Basically, you can't use the variable before it is initialized.